# Avoiding UnicodeEncodeError in python

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I tried to parse an [html table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors) into csv using python with a following script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


csvFile = open('log.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
def parse():
    html = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    table = bs.select_one('table.wikitable')
    rows = table.select('tr')
    for row in rows:
        csvRow = []
        for cell in row.findAll(['th', 'td']):
            csvRow.append(cell.getText())
        writer.writerow(csvRow)
        print(csvRow)


parse()
csvFile.close()
```

This code outputed a clear formated CSV file with no encoding issues.[image: an example]
All was just fine before Enrico Tröger's Geany. My script was unable to write `ö`
into a csv file, so i tried this:
`csvRow.append(cell.text.encode('ascii', 'replace'))` instead of that: `csvRow.append(cell.getText())`
All was fine, despite the fact that each table cell was nested in `b''`. [image] So, how can i get a clear formated csv file withous encoding issues(like in the first screenshot) and replaced or ignored all
non-unicode symbols(like in the second screenshot) using my scipt?

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback with the `UnicodeDecodeError` to the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this one:

```
csvFile = open('log.csv', 'w', newline='')
```

To this one:

```
csvFile = open('log.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8')
```

[`csv` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples):

> Since `open()` is used to open a CSV file for reading, the file will by default be decoded into unicode using the system default encoding (see [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding)). To decode a file using a different encoding, use the encoding argument of open:
>
> ```
> import csv
> with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
>     reader = csv.reader(f)
>     for row in reader:
>          print(row)
> ```
>
> The same applies to writing in something other than the system default encoding: specify the encoding argument when opening the output file.

I suppose your system default encoding is not `utf8`.
You can check it like this:

```
import locale
locale.getpreferredencoding()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That worked, but i needed to replace `csvRow.append(cell.text.encode('ascii', 'replace')` to `csvRow.append(cell.getText())`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the csv module expects strings, not `bytes`.  So you could de-encode your `bytes` before passing them:

```
cell.text.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode('ascii')
```